# Quotients of Frechet manifolds

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, global-analysis

In finite dimensions there is the quotient manifold theorem. Is there a generalization to infinite dimensions? Does anybody know references or maybe standard references for such questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about Frechet manifolds in ["Some recent work in Fréchet geometry"](https://www.emis.de/journals/BJGA/v17n2/B17-2-do.pdf) by **C. T. J. Dodson** and references therein. It is stated on page 8 that:

> Hausdorfness implies that a compact subset of a
> Fréchet  space is closed; a closed subspace is a Fréchet  space and a quotient
> by a closed subspace is a Fréchet  space.

You can find the same statement on page 4 of part I of "*Kähler Geometry of Loop Spaces*" by **Armen Sergeev** ([it is free](https://projecteuclid.org/ebook/Download?urlid=10.2969%2Fmsjmemoirs%2F02301C010&isFullBook=False)).

Comment: Are these statements about vector spaces, or about manifolds modelled on Frechet spaces?